# Не срабатывает preg_replace

Tags: php

При наборе в адресную строку `index.php` оно все равно не перенаправляет на `index` без `.php`. Пробовал на тесте строки – все работает нормально. В чем ошибка?

```php
$pattern = "/\.(php|html|asp|aspx|phtml|shtml)/i";

if(preg_match($pattern, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
   $currentPage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   $shortCut = preg_replace($pattern, "", $shortCut);
   header("Location:".$shortCut);
}
```

Comment: После `Location:` пробела нет, а после `header("Location:".$shortCut);` нет `exit();`

Comment: А должно что происходить? Как у вас связаны `$currentPage` и `$shortCut`?

Comment: @br3t У меня в конфиге сервера есть `Options +MultiViews` и если пользователь наберет `.php` в конце имени файла, то его все равно отправит на эту же страницу без `.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции `preg_replace()` вы используете не инициализированную переменную `shortCut`. В строке `$shortCut = preg_replace($pattern, "", $shortCut);`

Вероятно вы имели ввиду `$shortCut = preg_replace($pattern, "", $currentPage);`

Comment: Мда спасибо, я идиот. Сам бы себе минус поставил.